# Best way to automatically authenticate angular dot net core template application

Tags: angular, .net-core, identityserver4

I have created a dot net core 3.1 angular 8 template application with identity, the out-of-the-box offering. I have added the External Microsoft Account provider.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt()
                .AddMicrosoftAccount(options=> {
                    options.ClientId = microsoftClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = microsoftClientSecret;
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = microsoftAuthorizationEndpoint;
                    options.TokenEndpoint = microsoftTokenEndpoint;
                });
```

If I click on Login, it will redirect me to the Login page, where I can click on the Microsoft button, and have it redirect me to the External Microsoft login page. I can successfully log in to the application.

Instead of this, I want the application to automatically redirect to the External Microsoft provider when the application first runs. So instead of seeing the application home page, it would straight away go to the Microsoft login page (if not already logged in).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've already done part with authenticating and it works, but only problem is that you want to redirect user before page is rendered. If I'm right, I think the best solution would be using `CanActivate` guard, in which you can define your own way of checking if user is already authenticated before accesing route. You can read more about that here: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Is that an answer to your question?

Comment: No. If not authenticated, I want the application to immediately redirect to the external authorisation provider, which in this case is Microsoft. If I use an activation guard, it would just take me to the login page, where I would still need to click on the Microsoft button.

Comment: It will take you wherever you want to, why are you assuming that it will redirect you only to the login page?

Comment: You would have to know the structure of the request to the authentication provider. I don't know what the redirect url looks like, so how can I redirect there?